# Must declare the scalar variable ' ' error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a new column to the table with not null and default date time. But I get the error as below. I have checked multiple instances but the error occurs.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @date NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @date = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
                ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT @date';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This is the error I get.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

Any solution?

Comment: `sp_executesql`'s parameters does not works as variable substitution the way you use it. You will need to replace `@date` with that string literal when forming the dynamic alter table query

Comment: What's the point of this dynamic SQL statement? The default value is a pretty specific default that's unlikely to change between tables. It's also unexpected - the default update time is typically `GETDATE()` so it matches the insertion time. After that, update columns are updated using triggers

Comment: A useful improvement would be to change the obsolete `datetime` to `datetime2(0)` if you only want second precision, or something else if you want better precision. `datetime` has many quirks and one of them is that it's only accurate to around 0.003 seconds. [The docs strongly warn against using datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you really need milliseconds you'd need to use `datetime2(3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace `@date` with the value, it'll work.

But let's look at why it isn't working. Your SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @date NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @date = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
                ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT @date';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Declares a couple of variables and executes a block of SQL that one of the variables represents. Your issue is that `sp_executesql` reads some text as SQL and tries to run it - if you can't run what you tell it to run, then it can't.

So if you were to crack open a new query window and attempt to run:

```
ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
    ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT @date
```

It'd have a meltdown trying to figure out what `@date` is supposed to be.

```
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(1000);

SET @date = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000';

ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
    ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT @date;
```

Would work, or simply:

```
ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
    ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000';
```

So, using concatenation you can do:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @date NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @date = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
    
SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
                ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT ' + @date;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Which will get you a different error, so try including a pair of quotes in the `date` variable:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @date NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @date = '''9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'''
    
SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
                ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT ' + @date;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is like below where you create a dynamic SQL via concatenation

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @date NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @date = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [spi].[ProductClass]
                ADD lastUpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT default_updateTime DEFAULT '''+ @date+'''';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```